# Rotate image based in centroid using the rotation matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I found this [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8096278) were this guys rotated one egg image using the centroid.
I found the centroid based in the OTSU image:

```
_, thr = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
moment = cv2.moments(thr)
if moment['m00'] !=0 :
    centroid = (int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00']), int(moment['m01'] / moment['m00']))
    cv2.circle(result, centroid, 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    showImage(result, "Centroid")
```

[image]

The reasearches recomends use the rotation matrix to rotate the image using the centroid:

[image]

Could you help me how use the rotation matrix using opencv?

This is my current method, recently I found the centroid:

Input images:

[image]

[image]

```
def showImage(img, titulo):
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.title(titulo)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

# Segmentar
imagePath = "images/sample1.jpeg"
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
# convertir de formato BGR a RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
original = image
# Mostrar imagen original
showImage(image, "Imagen Original")

#Aplicar filtro paso bajo (blur)
image = cv2.blur(image,(9,9),0)
    
# Convertir a HSV:
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# Mostrar canal R el cual el huevo presenta mayor contraste
showImage(hsv, "hsv image")

# Convertir escala de grises el hsv
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
showImage(grayscale, "Escala de grises hsv")

# Aplicar binarización OTSU
_, thr = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

showImage(thr, "OTSU imagen")

# Poner máscara thr a la imágen original

result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=thr)

showImage(result, "Imagen segmentada")

# Buscar centroide
moment = cv2.moments(thr)
if moment['m00'] !=0 :
    centroid = (int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00']), int(moment['m01'] / moment['m00']))
    cv2.circle(result, centroid, 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    showImage(result, "Centroid")
```

Comment: Your question reminds me the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554673/how-can-i-draw-line-for-an-image-in-python). I think the solution may be applied to your problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment It describes the formula for the rotation in terms of moments

Comment: See also https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-survey-of-moment-based-techniques-for-unoccluded-Prokop-Reeves/cb42fe58273bbc8f39fd9064f5e8732b739a0139

Comment: Thanks dear @Rotem for share your work. Also fmw42 thanks so much for share that reference about image moments. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the warp functions including [**warpAffine**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html) and [**warpPerspective**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) in OpenCV. It seems that the **warpAffine** (affine transform) would be enough for your application. Anyway, you could simply use the below piece of code:

```
Point center = Point( image.cols/2, image.rows/2 );
Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D( center, angle, scale ); // rot_mat is 2x3 double matrix), you can set scale=1
Mat warp_rotate_dst;
warpAffine( image, warp_rotate_dst, rot_mat, image.size());
```